# Blender mouse problem

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

I have a problem with blender. Everytime when I click on an object on my viewport it makes me click a different object. For example whenever I click on the body of a human it makes me click the clothes instead. I need a solution to fix the dislocation of the mouse clicks. Especially when I'm in pose mode and  I click a specific bone it makes me click a different one.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3xqfj.jpg

Comment: Can you post some screen recordings of this behavior? At the moment your description is a little vague.

Comment: ok i will do it right now.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/p3bUhdd here

Answer (score 1):

You are currently in Pose Mode. You can click up here, and switch to Object mode to get back to the "Main" view, or Edit mode to get to the modeling view. The shortcut to switch is Ctrl+Tab.

[image]